# setting up ssl with express server

Tags: node.js, express

I was following this tutorial of setting up ssl within node.
http://blog.nategood.com/nodejs-ssl-client-cert-auth-api-rest

Here the certificate files are loaded by passing an options object to createServer

```
var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt'),
    requestCert:        true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    if (req.client.authorized) {
        res.writeHead(200, {&quot;Content-Type&quot;: &quot;application/json&quot;});
        res.end('{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;approved&quot;}');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(401, {&quot;Content-Type&quot;: &quot;application/json&quot;});
        res.end('{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;denied&quot;}');
    }
}).listen(443);
```

However I am using express for my application server needs.

The flow goes something like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Where do I pass in the certificate details ?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the express application object in `https.createServer` callback:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt'),
    requestCert:        true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000);
```